# CSS: adding specific css to a <li> element

Tags: css

I want one `<li>` inside of a `<ul>` that I don't want to be affected by the CSS that affects the rest of the `<li>` elements in the list.

I am trying to add an id or a class to the line item element, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to do this:

```
<li id="submit">
  <button id="seSubmitButton" class="btn btn-success" data-placeholder="SUBMIT">
    SUBMIT
  </button>
</li>
```

The css that affects this is here:

```
.dropdown-menu>li:hover {
  background-color: #f2c2c2;
}
```

I tried multiple things here:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>submit :hover {
  background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

like `.dropdown-menu>li submit` or just `.li submit`

but it's not picking it up.  What am I doing wrong with the specific syntax to make this specific `<li>` picked up by my CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the selector `li#submit` since the `li` element has an `id` of `submit`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/c4vgzLg2/)

```
.dropdown-menu>li#submit:hover {
  background-color: #a2a2a2;
}
```

---

You could also use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to negate the `li#submit` element when setting the initial styling that you are trying to overwrite:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zcL39frz/)

```
.dropdown-menu>li:not(#submit):hover {
  background-color: #f2c2c2;
}
```

Comment: Great.  Thank you for this!  Where can I read on the differences between all the different characters I could possibly put - `.` vs `#` vs `>` etc....

Comment: @JohnWu MDN is the best place.. Scroll down to "CSS Selectors" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: Why not? When you have no experience with basics w3schools is fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you added id, you can use it in your stylesheet to address the element:

```
#id {
    background-color: #f2c2c2;
}
#id:hover {
     /* some style */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#` while using `id` and dot(`.`) while using `class`.

for id

```
 #idName {
    /* css propery here */
    }
```

for class

```
.className {
    /* css propery here */
}
```